# Need assistance to use 'requests' and 're' modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am brand new to Python.  I need assistance to allow `html_content` to work correctly using `re.findall` in the below script.  I would prefer to only add the minimal code necessary for the existing lines to work correctly.  Thanks in advance!

```python
import requests
import re

title = 'this is a test'
html_content = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?', params={'search_query': title})

search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
```

**AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'**

Comment: The AttributeError means exactly what it says. `response` options *don't* have a `read()`. As you can see at https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/, you should refer to `html_content.text`

Comment: *Ideally*, consider using `lxml.html` instead of trying to run regexes on the response as text.

Comment: Maybe change `html_content.read()` to `html_content.text`.

Comment: (Also -- one question to a question, please; that is to say, better to ask a narrow question about `requests`, and a *separate* narrow question about `re`, than a question that conflates both -- that way you're also more likely to find preexisting instances already asked-and-answered, and not need to ask any new question at all).

Comment: Thanks so much!  html_content.text works great!